# Random UUID generation

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, uuid

Greetings fellow programmers,

I am writing a simple bluetooth application to discover devices and connect with them.
When I use the UUID "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" to connect with my laptop, everything works normal.
However, I can't make the code work when I try to connect to an android device using a generated UUID from the available online generators

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps the question [Android: How do bluetooth UUIDs work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964342/android-how-do-bluetooth-uuids-work) might help you.